# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is my action:

```
export async function load_todo(){

    const data = await fetch(url).then(data => data.json())

    return (dispatch) =>{
       dispatch({
           type: LOAD_TODO,
           payload: data
       })
    }
}
```

and I've already put `thunk` middleware in my store

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import reducers from './reducers/todo'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'


const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk))


export default store
```

and somehow I still end up with this error
[image]

what am I doing wrong in this code?

Comment: I guess it's because `load_todo` returns a Promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thunk would need to look like this:

```js
export function load_todo(){
    return async (dispatch) =>{
       const data = await fetch(url).then(data => data.json())
       dispatch({
           type: LOAD_TODO,
           payload: data
       })
    }
}
```

Putting the `async` keyword on `load_todo` will make that function return a promise of the inner function, not the inner function itself.

Comment: it worked!, but I got lost in the "return a promise of the inner function, not the inner function itself" my logic is because `load todo` is async it should wait for the `data` to finish the call before `return` got executed obviously I'm wrong, but why?

Comment: If you execute an `async` function, it immediately returns a Promise to the caller. That promise will resolve once your async function has done all their stuff and returns.